# how to read a byte from a text file as an actual byte in hex instead of characters?

Tags: java, hex, ascii, data-conversion

Im really unsure how to phrase my question, but here is the situation.

I have data in a text file, for example: 0x7B 0x01 0x2C 0x00 0x00 0xEA these values are a hex representation of ASCII symbols.  I need to read this data and be able to parse and translate accordingly.

My problem so far is that ive tried using a scanner via something like scan.getNextByte() and was directed towards the post: [using java.util.Scanner to read a file byte by byte]

After changing the file input format to a fileinputstream i found that while doing something like fis.read(), this is returning 48, the ascii value for the character 0 in 0x7B.

I am looking for a way to interpret the data being read in has hex so 0x7B will be equivalent to "{" in ASCII.

Hope this is clear enough to all,

Thanks,

Comment: You need to read in the whole "byte" - 0x7B instead of just 0 - into a string and then you can use something like `Integer.decode(hexString)`

Comment: Why do you have such a file in the first place? Not much use.

Comment: The file is being generated via serial communication and my applications job is to interpret based on our needs.  We have a 64k block flash memory that is being dumped into my lap and i need to be able to decode the header and generate files based off of that.

Comment: 0xEA is not a (whole nor part of an) ASCII code unit. If the data is text, which character set and encoding is used?

Answer (score 1):

Since your bytes are delimited by spaces, you can just use a Scanner to read them:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(filename))) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        int byteValue = Integer.decode(scanner.next());
        // Process byteValue ...
    }
}
```

I encourage you to read about the [Integer.decode method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode-java.lang.String-) and the [Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: This is close to what i was doing originally and was told this is a horrible way to handle the file because i am interested in reading one byte (2 characters) at a time.

Comment: @Tyler Your previous was question was a bit unclear, and frankly, I’m still not clear:  Does your file contain a *textual representation of each byte as four ASCII characters,* or are you just writing 0x7B etc. in your question in order to show *us* what raw bytes are in the actual data file?

Answer (score 1):

If you need scalable solution, try to write your own InputStream

Basic example:

```
class ByteStringInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final InputStream inputStream;

    public ByteStringInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    private boolean isHexSymbol(char c) {
        return (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
                || (c == 'x');
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {

        try {
            int readed;
            char[] buffer = new char[4];
            int bufferIndex = 0;

            while ((readed = inputStream.read()) != -1 && bufferIndex < 4) {
                if (isHexSymbol((char) readed)) {
                    buffer[bufferIndex] = (char) readed;
                }
                bufferIndex++;
            }

            String stringBuffer = new String(buffer);

            if (!stringBuffer.matches("^0x[0-9A-F]{2}$")) {
                throw new NumberFormatException(stringBuffer);
            }

            return Integer.decode(stringBuffer);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            inputStream.close();
            throw new IOException("<YOUR_EXCEPTION_TEXT_HERE>", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
ByteStringInputStream bsis = new ByteStringInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
//you can use any InputStream instead

while (true) {
    System.out.println(bsis.read());
}
```

Demo:

```
>0x7B 0x01 0x2C 0x00 0x00 0xEA
123
1
44
0
0
234
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're in a position to use external libraries, the [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library has a [Hex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) utility class that can turn a character-array representation of hex bytes into a byte array:

```
final String hexChars = "0x48 0x45 0x4C 0x4C 0x4F";
// to get "48454C4C4F"
final String plainHexChars = hexChars.replaceAll("(0x| )", "");
final byte[] hexBytes = Hex.decodeHex(plainHexChars.toCharArray());
final String decodedBytes = new String(hexBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Would it simplify things at all if the "0x" was not present? I believe i can manipulate the data before i receive it at this point so it would just be data like 7B 01 2C ...etc.

Comment: Yes, it would make things simpler if you got rid of the 0x and the spaces. It makes it a bit harder for humans to read, but the converter no longer needs to worry about the "filler" characters that don't contain any information.

Comment: In this case i would read two bytes at a time, "7", then "B" and concatenate them into a string, then to a hex value?  Am i understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes. "7B" is one byte worth of data, so to get a Java `byte`, you need to consider two characters at a time.